# Sync with Bing Maps geocoding services globally

Tags: batch-file, maps, geocoding, bing-maps, reverse-geocoding

my company has numerous locations throughout the world that require incredible response times for geocoding and reverse geocoding services...each location will submit global addresses and lat/longs with different volumes at different hours of their respective geo work day - .

Can anyone comment on whether Bing Maps is deployed globally to maximize geocoding performance and minimize latency?>?  and if so, how do I connect with the closest data center to effect tip top performance

Thank you!

JM

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is for you to ask this question at the Bing Maps Forum. It's a very active community and the Bing Maps Team monitors the threads very closely. If someone has an answer for you, it's them.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/threads